# Only show dropdown when you hover on it, or else hide the dropdown when you hover outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown on my webpage that works when you hover on it and it looks like this:

[Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjwKb.png)

The problem is that it doesn't close after hovering on it, i'd have to click outside the dropdown area for it to close and it overlaps other dropdowns which looks like this:

[Overlapping dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR0KQ.png)

So is it possible to hide the dropdown when I hover outside of it?

I've tried adding `display: none;` to the `dropdown` so it would only show up when you hover on it but it didn't work.

Anyway here's my code:

```css
.dropdown.share li:after,
.fade-1 .content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.dropdown.show,
.navigation li:hover:before {
  visibility: visible
}

.dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  color: #202020;
  width: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(.9);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(.9);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s, -webkit-transform .35s;
  transition: transform .35s, opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s;
  transition: transform .35s, opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s, -webkit-transform .35s
}

.dropdown:not(.show) {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0
}

.dropdown.rectangular {
  border-radius: 0
}

.dropdown .title {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .8
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: .6
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #EF4D26;
}

.dropdown:not(.noArrow):after,
.dropdown:not(.noArrow):before {
  content: "";
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 22px;
  border: solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-width: 7px;
  margin-left: -7px
}

.dropdown:not(.noArrow):before {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-left: -8px
}

.dropdown.show {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px)
}

.dropdown .hideDropdown,
.dropdown.show.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}

.dropdown.show.hide {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  transform: translateY(40px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}

.dropdown.bottom {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom
}

.dropdown.bottom.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px)
}

.dropdown.bottom.show.hide {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px)
}

.dropdown.bottom:after,
.dropdown.bottom:before {
  top: 100%;
  bottom: initial;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-top-color: #fff
}

.dropdown.bottom:before {
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .06)
}

.dropdown.right:after,
.dropdown.right:before {
  right: 18px;
  left: auto
}

.dropdown.right:before {
  right: 17px
}

.dropdown.center:after,
.dropdown.center:before {
  left: 50%
}

.dropdown.share li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 14px 0;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .9;
  transition: .15s
}

.dropdown.share li:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.dropdown.share li:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s
}

.dropdown.share li:active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s
}

.dropdown.share li svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: #fff
}

.dropdown.share li.mail {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: #202020;
  opacity: .6;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px
}

.dropdown.share li.mail:hover {
  opacity: .8
}

.scroll .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<a href="about-us">
  <li class="dropdownTrigger hover" data-dropdown-hover="true" data-dropdown-id="dropdown-ourstory"><strong style="opacity: .8;">Our Story</strong> <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: 10px;"></i></li>
</a>

<!-- Dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown top customDropdown center globalFont" data-dropdown-id="dropdown-ourstory" style="padding: 10px; line-height: 2em;">
  <ul>
    <li class="link"><a href="about-us#theteamspanblueprint"><strong style="font-size: 17px;">Our Game Plan</strong></a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="about-us#meettheteam"><strong style="font-size: 17px;">Our Team</strong></a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="about-us#ourimpact"><strong style="font-size: 17px;">Our Impact</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `:hover`. When you hover on to the dropdown make it as `display:block`. You can refer to [Dropdown on hover](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text).   Please remove the below from your code and add `main` div

```
/*code to be removed from your css*/
.dropdown:not(.show) {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0
}
```

Below is the code to be added in your css

```
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  color: #202020;
  width: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(.9);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(.9);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s, -webkit-transform .35s;
  transition: transform .35s, opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s;
  transition: transform .35s, opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s, -webkit-transform .35s
}
.main{
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main:hover .dropdown {
  display: block
}
```

Here is the complete working snippet for the same

```css
.dropdown.share li:after,
.fade-1 .content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.dropdown.show,
.navigation li:hover:before {
  visibility: visible
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  color: #202020;
  width: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(.9);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(.9);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s, -webkit-transform .35s;
  transition: transform .35s, opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s;
  transition: transform .35s, opacity .35s, box-shadow .35s, -webkit-transform .35s
}
.main{
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main:hover .dropdown {
  display: block
}

.dropdown.rectangular {
  border-radius: 0
}

.dropdown .title {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .8
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: .6
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #EF4D26;
}

.dropdown:not(.noArrow):after,
.dropdown:not(.noArrow):before {
  content: "";
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 22px;
  border: solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-width: 7px;
  margin-left: -7px
}

.dropdown:not(.noArrow):before {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-left: -8px
}

.dropdown.show {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px)
}

.dropdown .hideDropdown,
.dropdown.show.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}

.dropdown.show.hide {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  transform: translateY(40px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}

.dropdown.bottom {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom
}

.dropdown.bottom.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px)
}

.dropdown.bottom.show.hide {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px)
}

.dropdown.bottom:after,
.dropdown.bottom:before {
  top: 100%;
  bottom: initial;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-top-color: #fff
}

.dropdown.bottom:before {
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .06)
}

.dropdown.right:after,
.dropdown.right:before {
  right: 18px;
  left: auto
}

.dropdown.right:before {
  right: 17px
}

.dropdown.center:after,
.dropdown.center:before {
  left: 50%
}

.dropdown.share li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 14px 0;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .9;
  transition: .15s
}

.dropdown.share li:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.dropdown.share li:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s
}

.dropdown.share li:active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s
}

.dropdown.share li svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: #fff
}

.dropdown.share li.mail {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: #202020;
  opacity: .6;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px
}

.dropdown.share li.mail:hover {
  opacity: .8
}

.scroll .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <a href="about-us" >
      <li class="dropdownTrigger hover" data-dropdown-hover="true" data-dropdown-id="dropdown-ourstory"><strong style="opacity: .8;">Our Story</strong> <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: 10px;"></i></li>
    </a>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <div class="dropdown top customDropdown center globalFont" data-dropdown-id="dropdown-ourstory" style="padding: 10px; line-height: 2em;">
      <ul>
        <li class="link"><a href="about-us#theteamspanblueprint"><strong style="font-size: 17px;">Our Game Plan</strong></a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="about-us#meettheteam"><strong style="font-size: 17px;">Our Team</strong></a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="about-us#ourimpact"><strong style="font-size: 17px;">Our Impact</strong></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to do using jQuery, you can use `.hover()`

Comment: Sorry but I'm still gettign the same result.

Comment: Then please update the code in which you were getting an error. It would be difficult to say without seeing your code

Answer (score 1):

You should use this when it's not hovered:

```
display:none;
```

and change it to on :hover

```
display:block;
```

For Example :

```
.simple-class {

display:none;

}

.simple-class:hover {

display:block;

}
```